Given a recurrence relation and its closed form, how can I get the same result by solving its ODE?
Assume the following three-term recurrence relation
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+x(2n+1)]a_n-x(n+1)a_{n+1}-x n a_{n-1}=x (\delta_{n,0}-\delta_{n-1,0})
\end{equation}
for $n\ge 0$ and $\gamma$ and $x$ are real and positive parameters.
This can be expressed in a continued-fraction form and the solution has a closed form.
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+x]a_0-x a_1=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+3x]a_0-2x a_2-x a_0=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+5x]a_0-3x a_3-2x a_1=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    ...
\end{equation}
By solving it from the bottom to the top, we are able to express $a_0$ as
\begin{equation}
     a_0[\gamma+x-\frac{x^2}{\gamma+3x\frac{4x^2}{\gamma+5x...}}]=x-\frac{x^2}{\gamma+3x+\frac{4x^2}{\gamma+5x+...}}
\end{equation}
(Notice how the Kronecke delta functions give us two distinct non-homogenous terms).
If we define $z=1/x$, it can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
    a_0=1-\gamma z \frac{1}{1+\gamma z-\frac{1}{3+ \gamma z...}}=1-\gamma z \Gamma[0,\gamma z]
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma[s,a]$ is the incomplete gamma function.
This works. However, it required a lot of 'inspection' and guessing to get the closed form in terms of the incomplete gamma function.
I would like to solve the same recurrence relation using an alternative approach such as transforming it into an ODE and solving it.
This is my approach:
First, we shift the indices by +1. Define $n^{\prime}=n-1$ and $n^{\prime}\rightarrow n$ (to avoid overnotation)
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+x(2n+3)]a_{n+1}-x(n+2)a_{n+2}-x (n+1) a_{n}=x (\delta_{n+1,0}-\delta_{n,0})
\end{equation}
with $n\ge -1$.
Assume a generating function as an ordinary power series $A(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n a_n$ (Notice we start from 0 rather than -1, this is because $a_{-1}z^{-1}=0$). The recurrence relation then becomes
\begin{equation}
    [\gamma+x(2zD+3)]\frac{A(z)-a_0}{z}-x(zD+2)\frac{A(z)-a_0-a_1 z}{z^2}-x (zD+1) A(z)=x (\delta_{n+1,0}-\delta_{n,0})
\end{equation}
where we have used that any function $P(n)$ acting on $a_n$ gives $P(z D)$, where $D$ is the differential operator.
Now it is just acting with the $D$ operator and rearranging and I would get a first-order ODE with polynomial coefficients.
Three main questions:
1)Is this approach correct?

How do I deal with the Kronecker deltas I have?

Let's suppose I can solve the resulting ODE. I would then get $A(z)$. However, this is just the generating function of my recurrence relation. How would I then use this information to get the same close formula I got in my first part?



@Nemo You are talking about how to solve the ODE, right? But let's assume I manage to do so, how is the answer related to the closed form of the continued-fraction?

This question is similar to: Transform a recurrence relation into an ODE. What is the relation between the ODE solution and the CF closed form?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MaxAlekseyev Yes, it is similar to the question you sent, because I did that question. The question seemed too general and got no answers, so I made another post with a more specific example.

@MaxAlekseyev Actually, I think it is a better idea to delete the other post, which can be confusing.

This is not a research-level question and is more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/ Btw,  you have an error when you eliminated $n$ in the left-hand size but not in the righ-hand side.
